# Node-inspector in docker container using docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, node-inspector

I feel like I am close to getting docker-compose and node-inspector playing nicely together but would love if someone could show me how they set up their docker-compose file along with an explanation for how it works.

Here's what my compose.yml file looks like with just the node app in it:

```
  app:
    image: my-node-app
    volumes:
     - '~/mycode:/app/code'
    ports:
     - "3000:3000"
    command: /bin/bash
```

Also note I'm using Docker for Mac. (Although I don't think that should change much..)

I found a couple tutorials for getting for how to do it, but the information was either out of date or seemed incomplete. Here are the two main approaches (neither has worked for me yet):

1) From: https://github.com/seelio/node-inspector-docker/issues/1

```
app:
    image: my-node-app
    ports:
     - "3000:3000"
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes_from:
     - code
debugger:
    image: node-debug
    depends_on: 
      - app
    # `service` instead of `container` for an easier cold start
    network_mode: 'service:app'
    volumes_from:
      - code
code:
    image: node
    volumes:
     - '~/mycode:/app/code'
```

2)

and from: https://keylocation.sg/our-tech/debugging-nodejs-in-docker-using-node-inspector :

```
 debugger:
    container_name: debugger
    network_mode: host
    extends:
      service: base
    volumes:
      - /app/containers/debugger:/app/container
```

> One little trick required was the addition of port 5858 mapping for the node-app container so that Node Inspector can see it as port 5858 on the host:

```
 node-app:
    ports:
      - "5858:5858" # Port needs to be mapped to host so that debugger container can access it
```

Comment: FWIW if you're using node v6.3.0+ (IIRC) then you can use Chrome dev tools directly, without `node-inspector`.

Comment: That is great to know. Does it work when debugging a node script running in a docker container?

Comment: All it needs is a single port open, 9229 by default. Run your script like: `node --inspect --debug-brk foo.js` and it will display a URL on stdout that you visit in Chrome.

Comment: Wow that is pretty amazing! Node inspector is such a hassle to use. This is a huge incentive to upgrade to v6! Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `EXPOSE 5858` or `EXPOSE 9229` in your app Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

Node’s debug interface needs to know to be accessible outside of local network of Docker container, so the inspector should be started with

```
node --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229 index.js
```

Replace index.js with whatever node thing you want to run.

`--inspect-brk` is used instead of `--inspect` so that debugger can be attached at start of the script, so that it can follow whatever it does, which allows the debugger to know whatever is happening, effectively allowing proper debugging.

The broadcast IP causes the inspector listen everything and not closing connections from outside of localhost (the default). 9229 is the default port.